# TableQuery to case class

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

I have some for comprehension loop. Object used here were automatically generated from DB with slick.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator:

```
for {
  boxer <- Boxers.filter { b => b.address === someAddress }
  fullBoxer <- buildFullBoxer(boxer)
} yield {
  fullBoxer
}
```

The *buildFullBoxer* function takes a case class BoxersRow as a parameter so the loop does not compile and generates the error:

> type mismatch; found : models.Tables.Boxers required:
>   models.Tables.BoxersRow

The generated schema code is:

```
case class BoxersRow(id: Long, firstName: String, lastName: String, nick: Option[String] = None, boxingTypeId: Int = 0, birthDate: Option[java.sql.Date] = None, address: Option[String] = None, lastUpdated: java.sql.Timestamp)
implicit def GetResultBoxersRow(implicit e0: GR[Long], e1: GR[String], e2: GR[Option[String]], e3: GR[Int], e4: GR[Option[java.sql.Date]], e5: GR[java.sql.Timestamp]): GR[BoxersRow] = GR{
    prs => import prs._
    BoxersRow.tupled((<<[Long], <<[String], <<[String], <<?[String], <<[Int], <<?[java.sql.Date], <<?[String], <<[java.sql.Timestamp]))
}
class Boxers(_tableTag: Tag) extends Table[BoxersRow](_tableTag, "boxers") {
    def * = (id, firstName, lastName, nick, boxingTypeId, birthDate, address, lastUpdated) <> (BoxersRow.tupled, BoxersRow.unapply)
    def ? = (Rep.Some(id), Rep.Some(firstName), Rep.Some(lastName), nick, Rep.Some(boxingTypeId), birthDate, address, Rep.Some(lastUpdated)).shaped.<>({r=>import r._; _1.map(_=> BoxersRow.tupled((_1.get, _2.get, _3.get, _4, _5.get, _6, _7, _8.get)))}, (_:Any) =>  throw new Exception("Inserting into ? projection not supported."))

    val id: Rep[Long] = column[Long]("id", O.AutoInc, O.PrimaryKey)
    ....
}
lazy val Boxers = new TableQuery(tag => new Boxers(tag))
```

Of course I would not like to change automatically generated schema objects. The buildFullBoxer function reads additional data from DB and build a common FullBoxer object containing all necessary data.

```
private def buildFullBoxer(boxersRow: BoxersRow): DBIO[FullBoxer] = {
    val query = for {
      ((((boxer, fight), division), b1), b2) <-
      Boxers.filter(_.id === boxersRow.id)
        .joinLeft(Fights).on((b, f) => (b.id === f.firstBoxerId) || (b.id === f.secondBoxerId))
        .joinLeft(Divisions).on((bf, d) => bf._2.map { _.divisionId === d.id })
        .joinLeft(Boxers).on((bfd, b1) => bfd._1._2.map { _.firstBoxerId === b1.id } )
        .joinLeft(Boxers).on((bfdb1, b2) => bfdb1._1._1._2.map { _.secondBoxerId === b2.id } )
    } yield (boxer, fight, division, b1, b2)

    val action = query.result.map {case sequence => sequence.groupBy(x => x._1) }.
      map { _.map { case (box, tup) => (box, tup.map { case (b, f, d, b1, b2) => f.map { fight => (fight, d.getOrElse(throw NoDivisionException("No such a division: " + fight.divisionId)), b1.getOrElse(throw NoBoxerException("No boxer with id " + fight.firstBoxerId, Seq.empty, None)), b2.getOrElse(throw NoBoxerException("No boxer with id " + fight.secondBoxerId, Seq.empty, None)), Seq.empty) }  } map (_.map(FullFight.tupled)) flatten ) } toSeq }.
      map {_.map(FullBoxer.tupled).head }
    action
}
```

How could I pass the case class BoxersRow to buildFullBoxer function in this for comprehension loop?

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding another answer here, as you are not taking advantage of slicks querying capabilities. The workflow is generally Query -> Action -> Result. As a rule of thumb, stay as low as possible. This means work with `Query` until no longer possible. Then combine `DBIOAction` and finally if you really have to, start combining `Future` (Results).

One of slicks core features is, that you can combine and mix several queries into one. Something that is not possible in plain SQL. Your use case can easily be solved by mixing two Queries. It could look like this (untested code ahead):

```
object BoxerQuery {
   val findFullBoxers = {
     Boxers
      .joinLeft(Fights).on((b, f) => (b.id === f.firstBoxerId) || (b.id === f.secondBoxerId))
      .joinLeft(Divisions).on((bf, d) => bf._2.map { _.divisionId === d.id })
      .joinLeft(Boxers).on((bfd, b1) => bfd._1._2.map { _.firstBoxerId === b1.id } )
      .joinLeft(Boxers).on((bfdb1, b2) => bfdb1._1._1._2.map { _.secondBoxerId === b2.id } )
      .map { 
         case ((((boxer, fight), division), b1), b2) => (boxer, fight, division, b1, b2)
       }
   }

   def findFullBoxerByAddress(address: Rep[Address]) = findFullBoxers.filter(fbQuery => fbQuery._1.address === address)

   def findFullBoxerByWebaddress(webaddress: Rep[Webaddress] = findFullBoxers.filter(fbQuery => fbQuery._1.webaddress === webaddress)
}
```

The whole code block above is still on `Query` level. You can mix and combine queries as you like. A decent IDE is quite helpful here. If the query finally returns what you need, create an action that returns a `FullBoxer`:

```
val action: DBIOAction[Seq[FullBoxer]] = Query.findFullBoxerByAddress(address).result.map(_.groupBy(_._1).map {
  case (boxer, grp) => FullBoxer(
    boxer,
    grp.flatMap(_._2).distinct,
    grp.flatMap(_._3).distinct,
    grp.flatMap(_._4).distinct
  )
})
```

Now that we have everything in place, run `action` against the database and fetch all `FullBoxer` objects in a single round trip:

```
val fullBoxers: Future[Seq[FullBoxer]] = db.run(action)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Boxers.filter { b => b.address === someAddress }` returns just a query, not a result. A query can be composed and extended. Think of writing a strong typed SQL query. In order to get a result set, you need to run the query respectively action against a database.

So first you will need to create `DBIOAction`:`Boxers.filter(b => b.address === someAddress).result`. Actions can again be composed, but not extended anymore.

Secondly run that action against a database: `db.run(Boxers.filter(b => b.address === someAddress).result)`, whereas `db` is the `Database` object (see [Slick docs](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.1.1/gettingstarted.html#database-configuration)). `db.run` finally return s a `Future[Seq[BoxerRow]]`.

You can then run `buildFullBoxer` directly using `map`:

```
val fullBoxers: Future[Seq[WhateverBuildFullBoxerReturns]] = {
  db.run(Boxers.filter(b => b.address === someAddress).result).map { results =>
    results.map(boxer => buildFullBoxer(boxer))
  }
}
```

Comment: Exactly! However it will return something like DBIOAction[Seq[DBIOAction[Option[FullBoxer]]]] while DBIOAction[Seq[Option[FullBoxer]]] would be better. I am trying to make use of flatMap instead of map.

Comment: It might be helpful if you add a little more information about `buildFullBoxer()`. What is the signature? What is the purpose of this method? Are you trying to fetch additional information from the db?

Comment: Added a definition of the buildFullBoxer function. It is used for reading additional data from DB and build a common object containing all data indeed. Now the result of the findbyWebbaddres function is DBIOAction[Seq[MySQLDriverapi.DBIO[FullBoxer]]

Comment: Is there a specific reason to not get `FullBoxer` in one query? You could just  change `Boxers.filter(_.id === boxersRow.id)` to `Boxers.filter(_.address === someAddress)`.

Comment: The reason not to get FullBoxer in one query is that I would like to reuse this fragment. It's pretty complex and I would like to use the same buildFullBoxer functionality in functions like findByWebaddress, findByName, findById... changing only the query `Boxers.filter(b => b.address === someAddress)` to `Boxers.filter(b => b.name === name)` within.

Comment: The other idea to solve this problem is to pass on object of class Query or maybe TableQuery as an argument in the function buildFullBoxer. However the code `Boxers.filter(b => b.address === someAddress)` generates a `Query[Tables.Boxers, Tables.Boxers.TableElementType, Seq]` and I have no idea how to declare this class as an argument.